# How to use element specific settings in a jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have code that looks like:

```
(function($, window, undefined){
    var options, methods = {
        init : function(opts){

            options = $.extend({}, {
                width   : 800,
                height  : 600,
            }, opts);

            return this.each(function(){
                data = $(this).data('prodigal');
                if(!data){
                    $(this).data('prodigal', options).on('click', openl);
                }
            });
        },
    },
    openl = function(){
        console.log(options);
    };


    $.fn.prodigal = function(method) {
        // Method calling logic
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.prodigal' );
        }
    };
})(jQuery)
```

And I call it like:

```
$('.view_title_images').prodigal({width: 500});
$('.glglg').prodigal({ width: 600 });
```

The problem is when I output the `options` in `openl` I actually get both selectors showing a `width` setting of 600.

Up until recently I stored element specific info on the elements data tag: `$(this).data('prodigal', options)` and then acessed that data in every function I made so that `openl` would have a line at the top that goes like: `options = $(this).data('prodigal')`.

I did try and use public methods instead but I couldn't seem to bind those public methods in the `$(this).data('prodigal', options).on('click', openl);` line, it kept producing errors.

Should I still be trying to store my settings in my elements data tag or is there something I am missing about building jQuery plugins? How do I manage settings in a plugin?

This doesn't seem to be clearly covered by previous topics I have searched for.

Comment: Storing options in `data()` is the usual approach. Can you explain more about what errors you were getting when taking this approach?

Comment: Ah nah, that worked, the method I saw on here (which didn't work) was to use public methods pass the options around (lost the question now) but that didn't seem to work for me because I couldn't get the function to call the right one on bind, only inline like `$.fn.prodigal('open')` which really didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer as well, I am getting completely turned around by what peple say that you can do with options, everyone covers options globally but no one seem to really explain it and explain the part I mention in indepth and I look at other plugins code and it confuses me how they do it (fancybox is one that has been twisting me), but I think it is because I am just getting turned around. I need to focus on what I know after you said that.

Comment: @Matt If you wanna put that as an swer I will accept it, better than giving myself the mark since you re-inforced the idea with authority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this to a degree, as @Matt says:

> Storing options in data() is the usual approach.

And I have now come to the realisation I was doing nothing wrong.

The reason for this question was because, in the wild, I have seen many plugins created in many ways.

Due to a comment that is kind of linked: [Difference in $.extend calls in a plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797815/difference-in-extend-calls-in-a-plugin/13798839#comment18979510_13797870) I have been able to get hold of a set of "good" design patterns that I can use to suite my needs (that are not in the documentation): http://jqueryboilerplate.com/ as kindly provided by @Marcus in the linked comment.